# WPF saving control state

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

Writing a custom Listview control to persist it to a user's machine and have the state restored when the user runs the application again. I am assuming that this is not a trivial task and not worth the development effort. There are third party controls that provide this functionality. Would it be better in this case to buy vs build.

Comment: Why do you want to persist the listview vs the data the listview is displaying ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your custom Listview is build as MVVM pattern its Model may take rule to persist ListView state. Moreover you can to do it via Serialization so that it would be quite trivial task.